# Copy AJAX Control Toolkit CascadingDropDown on client

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, cascadingdropdown

I'd like to copy a cascading dropdownlist on client side via javascript (jQuery).

[image: Cascading Drowndown lists]

You can see in the first box the cascading dropdown lists to replicate. They will be rendered in ASP.NET with the CascadingDropDown Control of the AJAX Control Toolkit. This works perfectly.

When you click on "Add additional category" all dropdownlists of the firstbox will be copied. (See second box)

This is the click script for this action (using [clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) of jQuery):

```
categoryRow.clone(true, true).insertBefore(containerRow);
subCategory1Row.clone(true, true).insertBefore(containerRow);
subCategory2Row.clone(true, true).insertBefore(containerRow);
subCategory3Row.clone(true, true).insertBefore(containerRow);
```

The clone() function also copies the hidden ClientState field of the CascadingDropDown Control.

Unfortunately the cascading functionality of the copied CascadingDropDownLists does not work.

How can I best create/copy cascading drodwownlists? Or do you have any other ideas/better ways to do this?

Comment: I fear that copying the DOM will not work in this case. You will need to add another set of cascadingdropdowns to your page's Controls collection in a postback. I suggest creating a CategoryControl.ascx for convenience.

Comment: The reason why the cascading functionality goes away is because I believe when you are copying the drop down, the ID also gets copied. With jQuery having multiple ids in the DOM is a big no no.

Answer (score 1):

***"Unfortunately the cascading functionality of the copied CascadingDropDownLists does not work"***

that is because the original elements also registered with event listeners... the copied elements are indeed copied but, without those listeners.

how can you check it? in any modern browser (i preffer chrome) you can watch the elements of your HTML page when entering the development tools (hit F12 to get it on). each element has a map of active listeners.

[image: element with event listeners shown in chrome development tools]

**in short**: find the function that used to define the events in the **first place** for the **original elements** - then use this function to register your new copied elements.

***JUST MAKE SURE TO NOT REGISTER THE ORIGINAL ELEMENTS MORE THEN ONCE***. that will cause each event to fire up several times for each element.

Comment: hi Nagelfar thanks for the credit :) would you mind to edit your original post and share some lines of code? it might help users that will watch this post later on